# Полупрозрачный черный statusbar без toolbar и action bar

Tags: android, xml, material-design

В моем приложении я хочу сделать **полупрозрачный черный statusbar** как в новом дизайне приложения ВКонтакте. Должно получиться что-то вроде этого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что у меня есть на данный момент в **values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Но проблема в том, что он **не хочет менять вид statusbar**, он просто становится прозрачным и все.

**P.S.** тестирую на Meizu M3E и вот что в итоге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>
```

На

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#77000000</item>
```

`FF` в переводе на десятичный формат равно `255`, т.е. 100% прозрачности, а если вы хотите только 50%, используйте `77` (это `127` в десятичной системе исчисления).

Comment: Осторожнее с порядком `#AARRGGBB` vs `#RRGGBBAA` - в какой-то версии планируется переход на html-совместимое представление.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, приму к сведению. а разве есть какая-то альтернатива в хмл? Во всех исходниках android используется `#AARRGGBB`.

Comment: @Соколов не помогло. Status bar, конечно, стал серым, а не прозрачным, но он теперь не поверх основного контента расположен а просто над ним (это если убрать android:windowTranslucentStatus), а если оставить android:windowTranslucentStatus, то он снова становится абсолютно прозрачным, но поверх контента как на скрине выше